# How can I make my android app not crash when TextEdit values that are called are left blank? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on a simple tip calculator app, and it works well in general so far. However, If my TextEdits are empty, my app force closes when the "calculate" button is clicked. I have been unable to find a solution for this and anything somewhat similar I find online or on StackOverflow is in Java.

This is the function that gets called when my button is pressed:

```kotlin
@SuppressLint("UseSwitchCompatOrMaterialCode")
    fun calculateTip() {
        var mealCost: Double = cost_of_service.text.toString().toDouble()
        var splitNum: Double = split_num.text.toString().toDouble()

        val selectedId = tip_options.checkedRadioButtonId
        val tipPercentage = when(selectedId) {
            R.id.option_twenty_percent -> 0.20
            R.id.option_eighteen_percent -> 0.18
            else -> 0.15}

        //original values
        var tip: Double = tipPercentage * mealCost
        var addedCost: Double = tip + mealCost
        var split: Double = addedCost / splitNum

        //finds some views
        val switch: Switch = findViewById(R.id.round_up_switch)
        val result: TextView = findViewById(R.id.tip_result)
        val total: TextView = findViewById(R.id.total_cost)
        val splitResult: TextView = findViewById(R.id.split_cost)
        val roundUp = switch.isChecked
        var splitString: String = split.toString()

        //if roundup switch is checked, rounds tip up
        if (roundUp) {
            tip = kotlin.math.ceil(tip)
            addedCost = kotlin.math.ceil(addedCost)
            split = kotlin.math.ceil(split)}

        //formats the tip to $
        val formattedTip = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(tip)
        val formattedCost = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(addedCost)
        val formattedSplit = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(split)

        //changes the textViews in the app
        result.text = getString(R.string.tip_amount, formattedTip)
        total.text = getString(R.string.total_amount, formattedCost)
        splitResult.text = getString(R.string.split_cost, formattedSplit)
    }
```

At this is the error that shows through Logcat when I press it without filling in my TextEdit values.

```
2020-10-09 17:59:49.446 21872-21872/com.gradient.tiptime E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.gradient.tiptime, PID: 21872
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
        at com.gradient.tiptime.MainActivity.calculateTip(MainActivity.kt:25)
        at com.gradient.tiptime.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:19)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7192)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7166)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:824)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27592)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

I apologize for the long question. I have been trying to solve this problem for a while now, but couldn't really find an answer. Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the first two lines of `calculateTip` method

```
var mealCost: Double = cost_of_service.text.toString().toDouble()
var splitNum: Double = split_num.text.toString().toDouble()
```

If the EditTexts are empty `cost_of_service.text.toString()` returns empty String, converting an empty String to a Double causes the crash.

To solve this you could use `.toDoubleOrNull()` instead of `.toDouble()` and write something like this:

```
var mealCost: Double = cost_of_service.text.toString().toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0
var splitNum: Double = split_num.text.toString().toDoubleOrNull() ?: 1.0
```

(splitNum is set to 1.0 since you don't want to divide with 0)

If you don't know what `?:` is, it's called Elvis operator, you can read more about it [on Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator). It basically performs a null check and sets the value on the right side if the left side is null.